# " setValue does not exists on type AbstractControl" for emptying form in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

My template,

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" novalidate="novalidate">
        <textarea [ngClass]="{ 'error': comment }"  
                  [formControl]="form.controls['comment']"  
                  placeholder="Comment...."></textarea>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" id="template-contactform-submit" 
               name="template-contactform-submit"  
               value="submit">Enter</button>
    </div>
```

my TS:

```
for(var prop in form) {
   if(this.form.controls.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      this.form.controls[prop].setValue(" ");
   }
}
```

I am getting the error as " setValue does not exists on type AbstractControl".

Comment: try this `this.form.controls[prop].setValue(" ")`

Comment: Micronycs,i am getting the error in my vsc " setValue does not exists on type AbstractControl"

Comment: Cast it to FormControl: (this.form.controls[prop] as FormControl).setValue()

Comment: it says error cannot find FormControl.....

Comment: Seems you are not on the newest Angular2 version. AFAIK this was added to `AbstractControl` not too long ago because many run into this error.

Comment: The plunker I provided him http://plnkr.co/edit/oGCsZr?p=info which contains the answer to his original problem is on a more up to date version per @Günter.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(<FormControl>this.form.controls[prop]).setValue(" ");
```

also import `FormControl` to make it work as

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to double check the error you are getting.

Firstly, just a sanity check - the error message shown in question is:

> setValue does not exists on type AbstractControl

wile TS compiler would say

> Property 'setValue' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

so, the inconsistency leads to assurance if the wrong method call is really **`setValue`**, and not something else.

Secondly - the **`setValue`** DOES EXIST on **`AbstractControl`**. Check the [AbstractControl source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L366)

```
export abstract class AbstractControl {
    ...
    /**
     * Sets the value of the control. Abstract method (implemented in sub-classes).
     */
    abstract setValue(value: any, options?: Object): void;
```